# An error occurs when trying to show an image using the "img" tag in react

Tags: reactjs

This is my code. The image can be found at the path provided by `this.state.imagepath` but an error is showing.

```
<*img src={require("./upload/"+this.state.imagepath)} alt={<div>Please select an image to preview</div>}/>
```

//this is my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Edit extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        itemid:this.props.match.params.id,
        mitemid:"",
        itemname:"",
        qty:null,
        price:null,
        imagepath:""


    }

    this.onIDValueChange=this.onIDValueChange.bind(this);
    this.onNameValueChange=this.onNameValueChange.bind(this);
    this.onQtyValueChange=this.onQtyValueChange.bind(this);
    this.onPriceValueChange=this.onPriceValueChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleImage=this.handleImage.bind(this);




}


onIDValueChange (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
      mitemid: event.target.value
  });
}

onNameValueChange (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
      itemname: event.target.value
  });
}
onQtyValueChange (event) {
event.preventDefault();
this.setState({
    qty: event.target.value
});
}

onPriceValueChange (event) {
event.preventDefault();
this.setState({
    price: event.target.value
});
}



componentDidMount(){
    const item ={

        itemid: this.state.itemid

      }

          fetch('http://localhost:4000/index/retrieveone',{
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(item)
          })
          .then(response => response.json())

        .then((res) => {


            this.setState({

              itemname:res.itemname,
              mitemid:res.itemid,
              qty:res.qty,
              price:res.price,
              imagepath:res.imagepath


           });

        })




}


handleSubmit(){

        fetch('http://localhost:4000/index/foodupdate/'+this.state.itemid,{
          method:"POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body:JSON.stringify({
            itemname:this.state.itemname,
            itemid:this.state.itemid,
            qty:this.state.qty,
            price:this.state.price,
          })
        })
        .then(response => response.json())

}

  handleImage(){

    return <img src={require("./upload/"+this.state.imagepath)} alt="No image to preview"/>;    
  }


  render() {

    return (
        <div className="container">
               <div>  
        <hr/>
        <div style={{backgroundColor:"#FFF0F5" }}>
        <div className="form-group" >
          <label className="col-lg-3 control-label">Item ID:</label>
          <div className="col-lg-8">
          <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.mitemid} onChange={this.onIDValueChange} />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="col-lg-3 control-label">Item name:</label>
          <div className="col-lg-8">
          <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.itemname} onChange={this.onNameValueChange}/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
              <label className="col-lg-3 control-label">Price (Rs):</label>
          <div className="col-lg-8">
          <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.onPriceValueChange}/>
          </div>
          </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label className="col-lg-3 control-label">Available Quantity:</label>
          <div className="col-lg-8">
          <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.qty} onChange={this.onQtyValueChange}/>
          </div>
          </div>





          <div className="form-group">
          <label className=" control-label"></label>



                 <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style={{margin:"20px" }} onClick={this.handleSubmit} >
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Update
                 </button> 

                </div>

                <div className="imgPreview">            
                       {this.handleImage}
                </div>



                 <div className="form-group">
                      <label className=" control-label"></label>
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-sm" style={{margin:"20px" }} >
                    Change Image
                 </button> 
                </div>






                </div>
         </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Edit;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? And how do you obtain the `imagepath` state variable?

Comment: Yes the path is correct. The image is displayed when I copy the string value of "this.state.imagepath" to the url directly. It does not work when it is used as a variable

Comment: I obtain the imagepath from the server/database along with other details.

Comment: Please include more code in your question, component and error message preferably.

Answer (score -1):

I have made this mistake myself. Quite frankly, dynamically rendering images in ReactJS takes a little bit of finesse (very annoying).

Your current code does not work because it does not know what this.state.imagepath means. The require method can only read a string. So, if you want to inject a variable you have to try using a string literal.

```
render() {
  const { imagepath } = this.state;
  return (
    ...
     <img src={require(`./upload/${imagepath}`)} alt={"please select an image..."} /> etc.
```

Assuming the imagepath is the actual path. Also, your ./upload/... has to be exact. Make sure upload is actually within your current directory. To be sure just right click your upload directory and select copy relative path. Paste that in your require string literal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you try updating imagepath before mounting using componentWillMount? This will cause an issue if your path is coming from the server side.

Comment: another thing you can do is create a method and return the img tag and call that method upon rendering. have you tried that already? What exactly is the error? Because it could be that your imagepath has not updated. For example, if you updated your imagepath using setstate and then immediately after try to render the image it may be undefined.

Comment: What you did is just destructing the state variables. It doesn't alter the app behavior at all.

Comment: no that's not all. I used a string literal which allows me to use a variable in an otherwise string only method. notice the back ticks and the ${}. this allows for variables to be used.

Comment: i've used this method in practice and it works just fine. @SlawomirWozniak could you tell me what error you got from this? or why you don't think it works?

Comment: @BensSteves, I tried your first suggestion. It does not work. Shows the same error.

Comment: @BensSteves, I tried creating a method too. It does not show any error, but the image is still not showing

Comment: @BensSteves, what did you mean by componentWillMount thing? I did'nt understand it. btw, my fetch method is in the componentDidMount(). image path is assigned from there.

Comment: handleImage(){
    
    return <img src={require("./upload/"+this.state.imagepath)} alt={<div>Please select an image to preview</div>}/>;    
  }
 <div className="imgPreview">            
                       {this.handleImage}
                </div> (above is my method and method calling)

Comment: @BensSteves It indeed works, but doesn't change any behavior. @Chiranga did concatenation, and so did you, but in other way. `"abc" + variable` is the same as ``abc${variable}``